# Error: text.replace is not a function in angularjs filter, how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

in the angular i trying to use filter in angular to replace some string with another word that it can find, i already try many example, i think my code is just missing something, but i can't figure it out. Here is my code :

here is my app.js

```
    app.filter('filterStatus', function () {
    return function (text) {

        if(text == 1){
            return str = text.replace(/1/g, "Waiting");
        } else if (text == 2) {
            return str = text.replace(/2/g, "On Process");
        } else if (text == 3) {
            return str = text.replace(/3/g, "On The Way");
        } else if (text == 4) {
            return str = text.replace(/4/g, "Delivered");
        } else if (text == 5) {
            return str = text.replace(/5/g, "Expired");
        }
    };
});
```

i going to replace "1" with "Waiting" word, here is my html page

```
            <tr ng-repeat-start="siheaders in singleID.siheader">
                <td>{{siheaders.status | filterStatus}}</td>
            </tr>
```

but it give me these "Error: text.replace is not a function" error when i use firebug to debug it, what am i missed here?

Comment: Is `siheaders.status` a string? Looks to me like you are expecting a number.

Comment: Does that variable contain a string or a number? `replace()` is a string method. What does `console.log(typeof text)` show you? I notice your if/else structure is comparing the variable to numbers, not strings (though `==` will return true for `"1"==1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no need to do any string replacement.

```
app.filter('filterStatus', function () {
    return function (text) {
        if(text == 1){
            return "Waiting";
        } else if (text == 2) {
            return "On Process";
        } else if (text == 3) {
            return "On The Way";
        } else if (text == 4) {
            return "Delivered";
        } else if (text == 5) {
            return "Expired";
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Or create a map to avoid the if elses